# Delete a row from a database getting the worker`s id depending of the chose worker`s name

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, wpf, visual-studio-2015

I have a Windows Presentation Foundation, I have a Database called "Worker" and a table that belongs to this Database, the table is called TestTable,with 6 columns: Id,Name, Lastname, Gender, Email and Password,  I already added some elements,in the Mainwindow the user can see all the information contained in the database columns except Id, I kept Id out of user`s sight, so I have different Listboxs with the information: ListboxNames, ListboxLastnames, ListboxGenders, etc...I made a method that allows me to delete rows from the Database according to the ListboxNames.SelectedItem, but it deletes using the name, which is not convenient because there could be several equal names, could you explain me how to get the correct id according to the ListboxNames.SelectedItem, how could I delete using the Id selecting a name from the ListBox?? Remember I never show the Id to the usser, thanks beforehand!!!
This is the method I use to delete, I guess I need to get the ids with the same name from the database maybe first and then I must choose between the ids the correct one, you just let me know!

```
 private void buttonDelete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "delete from TestTable where name='" + listBoxListNames.SelectedItem + "'";
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        listBoxListNames.Items.Clear();
        listBoxListLastnames.Items.Clear();
        listBoxListGenders.Items.Clear();
        listBoxListEmails.Items.Clear();
        listBoxListPasswords.Items.Clear();
        ShowDatabase();
    }
```

Comment: First you must run `select` query to get ID, Then after run `delete` query. Impossible to get ID in `delete query`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SelectedValue` property of listbox in this case; for that you need to bind the list box in following way:

Listbox definition:

```
<ListBox Name="myList" SelectedValuePath="myID" DisplayMemberPath="myTextField"... />
```

Binding:

```
DataTable myDataTable= getDataTable();//populate datatable from database
myList.SelectedValuePath = "myID";
myList.DisplayMemberPath = "myTextField";
myList.ItemsSource = myDataTable;
```

Then you can re-write your code to delete items using `SelectedValue` :

```
private void buttonDelete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    cmd.CommandText = "delete from TestTable where itemID=@myID";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("myID", myList.SelectedValue);
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
   //Do rest of operations here
}
```

Note : You have to use `parameterized` query to avoid injection; so take a look into the query too

Comment: Nice answer. Might as well parameterized the sql query.

Comment: Please do not use `AddWithValue`. Use `Parameters.Add()` instead. See [this article](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) for more info.